# Objective-C closure translated to Swift but keeps being run repeatedly without completing and without error

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures

The Swift version of the program compiles and runs without any errors.  However, it seems to be repeating at the line containing "as! TSLTransponderDataReceivedBlock" with the result as indicated on the right of that line.  The program execution never goes past that line of code. If this particular closure is commented out, the rest of the code seems to function as expected except for the missing functionality.

```
Objective-C Code that works as expected
----------------------------------------
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.csvString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"DATE,EPC,FTID,INDX,PC,CRC,RSSI\n"];
// Use the single
_commander = ((TSLAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).commander;

// This formatter will convert any timestamps received
_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
_dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

// Note: the weakSelf is used to avoid warning of retain cycles when self is used in Blocks
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;


//
// Performing an inventory could potentially take a long time if many transponders are in range so it is best to handle responses asynchronously
//
// The TSLInventoryCommand is also a TSLAsciiResponder for inventory responses and can have a transponderDataReceivedBlock
// that is informed of each transponder as it is received

// Create a TSLInventoryCommand
_inventoryResponder = [[TSLInventoryCommand alloc] init];

//
// Use the TransponderData-based per transponder Block callback
//
_inventoryResponder.transponderDataReceivedBlock = ^(TSLTransponderData *transponder, BOOL moreAvailable)
{
    // Append the transponder EPC identifier and RSSI to the results
    weakSelf.partialResultMessage = [weakSelf.partialResultMessage stringByAppendingFormat:@"Date: %@   EPC: %@   Indx: %@   RSSI: %@\n\n",
                                     (transponder.timestamp == nil ) ? @"n/a" : [weakSelf.dateFormatter stringFromDate: transponder.timestamp],
                                     (transponder.epc == nil ) ? @"n/a" : transponder.epc,
                                     (transponder.index == nil ) ? @"n/a" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04X", transponder.index.unsignedIntValue ],
                                     (transponder.rssi == nil ) ? @"n/a" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3d", transponder.rssi.intValue]
                                     ];

    // This line saves the RFID tag info to the string that will be written out to the CSV file.
    self.csvString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.csvString, weakSelf.fullResultMessage];

    weakSelf.transpondersSeen++;

    // If this is the last transponder add a few blank lines
    if( !moreAvailable ) {
        weakSelf.partialResultMessage = [weakSelf.partialResultMessage stringByAppendingFormat:@"\nTransponders seen: %4d\n\n", weakSelf.transpondersSeen];
        weakSelf.transpondersSeen = 0;
    }

    // This changes UI elements so perform it on the UI thread
    // Avoid sending too many screen updates as it can stall the display
    if( !moreAvailable || _transpondersSeen < 3 || _transpondersSeen % 10 == 0 ) {
        [weakSelf performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(updateResults:) withObject:weakSelf.partialResultMessage waitUntilDone:NO];
        weakSelf.partialResultMessage = @"";
    }
};


Swift 3 code that keeps repeating and never gets past the end of the closure:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    csvString = "DATE,EPC,FTID,INDX,PC,CRC,RSSI\n"
    // Use the single
    commander = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? TSLAppDelegate)?.commander
    // This formatter will convert any timestamps received
    dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter?.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter?.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        // Note: the weakSelf is used to avoid warning of retain cycles when self is used in Blocks
    weak var weakSelf: TSLInventoryViewController? = self
    //
    // Performing an inventory could potentially take a long time if many transponders are in range so it is best to handle responses asynchronously
    //
    // The TSLInventoryCommand is also a TSLAsciiResponder for inventory responses and can have a transponderDataReceivedBlock
    // that is informed of each transponder as it is received
    // Create a TSLInventoryCommand
    inventoryResponder = TSLInventoryCommand()
    //
    // Use the TransponderData-based per transponder Block callback
    //
    // Append the transponder EPC identifier and RSSI to the results
    weakSelf?.inventoryResponder!.transponderDataReceivedBlock = {(transponder: TSLTransponderData, moreAvailable: Bool) -> Void in
        weakSelf!.partialResultMessage = weakSelf!.partialResultMessage.appendingFormat("Date: %@   EPC: %@   Indx: %@   RSSI: %@\n\n",
            (transponder.timestamp == nil) ? "n/a" : (weakSelf!.dateFormatter?.string(from: transponder.timestamp))!,
            (transponder.epc == nil) ? "n/a" : transponder.epc,
            (transponder.index == nil) ? "n/a" : String(format: "%04X", CUnsignedInt(transponder.index)),
            (transponder.rssi == nil) ? "n/a" : String(format: "%3d", CInt(transponder.rssi)))

        // This line saves the RFID tag info to the string that will be written out to the CSV file.
        weakSelf?.csvString = "\(weakSelf?.csvString ?? "n/a") \(weakSelf!.fullResultMessage)"
        weakSelf!.transpondersSeen += 1
        // If this is the last transponder add a few blank lines
        if !moreAvailable {
            weakSelf!.partialResultMessage = weakSelf!.partialResultMessage.appendingFormat("\nTransponders seen: %4d\n\n", weakSelf!.transpondersSeen)
            weakSelf!.transpondersSeen = 0
        }
        // This changes UI elements so perform it on the UI thread
        // Avoid sending too many screen updates as it can stall the display
        if !moreAvailable || self.transpondersSeen < 3 || self.transpondersSeen % 10 == 0 {
            weakSelf!.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.updateResults), with: weakSelf!.partialResultMessage, waitUntilDone: false)
            weakSelf!.partialResultMessage = ""
        }
    } as! TSLTransponderDataReceivedBlock         //Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10003a878)
....
}
```

Your suggestions were greatly appreciated - Thank you.

The "weakSelf?" prefix to the inventory.Responder!.transponderDataReceivedBlock reference was removed and this did not make a difference.  In addition, all of the code in the closure was removed leaving only the actual closure structure and even the empty closure is showing the same behaviour.  Since the TSLTransponderDataReceivedBlock is defined and being processed in the original Objective-C API source code, it seems most likely that there is a problem with how Swift is setting up the closure structure for Obj-C to use.

The Objective-C definition of the TSLTransponderDataReceivedBlock from using "Jump to Definition" is:

```
///
/// The block type to handle transponder information received
///
/// @param transponder - the transponder information provided as a TSLTransponderData instance
/// @param moreAvailable - YES if there are more transponders to be delivered
///
typedef void(^TSLTransponderDataReceivedBlock)(TSLTransponderData *transponder, BOOL moreAvailable);
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `TSLTransponderDataReceivedBlock`

Comment: And, after creating `TSLInventoryCommand()` delete `weakSelf?.` from the line `weakSelf?.inventoryResponder!.transponderDataReceivedBlock = {(transponder: TSLTransponderData, moreAvailable: Bool) -> Void in`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was the following:

1) Change:
} as! TSLTransponderDataReceivedBlock
To:
}
Comment: eliminate the "as!" specifier

2) Change:
weakSelf?.inventoryResponder!.transponderDataReceivedBlock = {(transponder: TSLTransponderData, moreAvailable: Bool) -> Void in

To:
inventoryResponder!.transponderDataReceivedBlock = {(_ transponder: TSLTransponderData?, _ moreAvailable: Bool) -> Void in

Comment: remove the weakSelf? reference

Note: The final working build was done with Xcode 9 Beta 4 / Swift 4